# icon centered on hr in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I want to design a horizontal line with an icon on top of it, like [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/5ptdho8p/1/), but in react native. Something in the direction of:

```
<View style={{}}>
  <View style={{}}>
  <Image style={{}} source={}/>
</View>
```

[image]
How would I do this?

Comment: One way would be to give child `View` a horizontal border (`borderBottom` or `borderTop`) and put `position: 'absolute'` with some margins on `Image`.

Comment: @Sventies I added a live demo as well for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 100, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <View style={{ borderBottomColor: '#bdbdbd', borderBottomWidth: 1, width: '90%' }} />
        <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
              uri: 'http://www.cgbconstrucciones.com/en/templates/rt_clarion/images/icons/green-leaf-icon.png',
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -20,
    left: -20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
});
```

Check out the demo here https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/absolute-position

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, borderBottomColor: '#bdbdbd', borderBottomWidth: 1}} />
      <Image style={{width: 40, height: 40}}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://www.cgbconstrucciones.com/en/templates/rt_clarion/images/icons/green-leaf-icon.png',
        }}/>
      <View style={{flex: 1, borderBottomColor: '#bdbdbd', borderBottomWidth: 1}} />
    </View>
```